# Actuator api gives 404 in audit log

Tags: java, spring-boot

Below is the config I set in application.yaml:-

#Actuator
management:
endpoints:
web:
base-path: /manage
exposure:
include: "env,health,heapdump,info,metrics,prometheus,scheduledtasks,threaddump"
metrics:
se-global-registry: false
export:
prometheus:
enabled: true # Whether exporting of metrics to Prometheus is enabled.
step: 1m # Step size (i.e. reporting frequency) to use.

After deploying the application If I hit below api in Postman:-

http://localhost:{PORT}/manage/health

Response:-
{
"status": "UP"
}

But when I see the audit.log I find:-
2024-01-02T07:29:34.098Z|2024-01-02T07:29:34.099Z|1000d5d0-b6a3-4cac-bc84-bccee95ad1e0||http-nio-9100-exec-5||manage/health|m30746@non-prod.mso.ecomp.att.com|INPROGRESS||||INFO||172.18.0.18|0|apih.so.testlab.onap.org|||||ENTRY|Uri-Base=http://localhost:9100/, RequestID=1000d5d0-b6a3-4cac-bc84-bccee95ad1e0, InstanceID=e63f406f-13f1-4126-b222-cf961dfd6caa, ElapsedTime=0, OriginalPartnerName=m30746@non-prod.mso.ecomp.att.com, PartnerName=m30746@non-prod.mso.ecomp.att.com, ServerFQDN=apih.so.testlab.onap.org, ClientIPAddress=172.18.0.1, StatusCode=INPROGRESS, ServiceName=manage/health, ServerIPAddress=172.18.0.18, EntryTimestamp=2024-01-02T07:29:34.098Z, ServerInvocationId=c2876b08-7cc9-44f6-a8cd-9a025cdd1582, InvocationID=c2876b08-7cc9-44f6-a8cd-9a025cdd1582, LogTimestamp=2024-01-02T07:29:34.098Z|||Entering
2024-01-02T07:29:34.098Z|2024-01-02T07:29:34.100Z|1000d5d0-b6a3-4cac-bc84-bccee95ad1e0||http-nio-9100-exec-5||manage/health|m30746@non-prod.mso.ecomp.att.com|ERROR|404|Not Found||INFO||172.18.0.18|2|apih.so.testlab.onap.org|||||EXIT|Uri-Base=http://localhost:9100/, ResponseCode=404, RequestID=1000d5d0-b6a3-4cac-bc84-bccee95ad1e0, InstanceID=e63f406f-13f1-4126-b222-cf961dfd6caa, ElapsedTime=2, OriginalPartnerName=m30746@non-prod.mso.ecomp.att.com, PartnerName=m30746@non-prod.mso.ecomp.att.com, ServerFQDN=apih.so.testlab.onap.org, ClientIPAddress=172.18.0.1, StatusCode=ERROR, ServiceName=manage/health, ServerIPAddress=172.18.0.18, ErrorDesc=Not Found, EntryTimestamp=2024-01-02T07:29:34.098Z, ServerInvocationId=c2876b08-7cc9-44f6-a8cd-9a025cdd1582, InvocationID=c2876b08-7cc9-44f6-a8cd-9a025cdd1582, ErrorCode=404, LogTimestamp=2024-01-02T07:29:34.100Z, ResponseDesc=Not Found|||Exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Hi 404 indicates that your `manage/health` endpoint is not found but it should not be the case if you have properly configured your endpoint in your `application.yaml` if not please verify if you have configured your endpoint like below:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /manage
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

**Make sure that you've configured your base-path as `/manage` as you're trying to hit `http://localhost:{PORT}/manage/actuator/health`**

If it still continues, please check if you've added the actuator dependency properly.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I hope this helpes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am able to get below response(200) now in POSTMAN:-
{
    "status": "UP",
    "components": {
......
}
But still dont know why my audit log says:-
2024-01-02T08:04:03.543Z|2024-01-02T08:04:03.641Z|b86598da-d01e-4b63-be78-16b353bea41b||http-nio-9100-exec-2||manage/health|m30746@non-prod.mso.ecomp.att.com|ERROR|404|Not Found||INFO||172.19.0.14|98|apih.so.testlab.onap.org|||||EXIT|Uri-Base=http://localhost:9100/, ResponseCode=404, RequestID=b86598da-d01e-4b63-be78-16b353bea41b,ErrorCode=404, LogTimestamp=2024-01-02T08:04:03.641Z, ResponseDesc=Not Found|||Exiting

Comment: This should not be the case, is it an automated HealthCheck or whenever you're hitting your actuator that time, you're seeing these logs? Are you using any kind of authorization in your application?

Comment: I am seeing this when ever I am hitting the actuator api.
No there is no authorization

Comment: Try to check if you have any interceptor for the Auditing may be there is something wrong anyhow your actuator is working and you're able to see it's status so now your issue is related to Auditing and you need to provide your audit code how you're doing Auditing